# Display html or multiline message in ValidationMessage in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

**Problem**

Display list of error messages for password as below:

1. Must contain at least one upper case letter.
2. Must contain at least one lower case letter.
3. Must contain at least one number.
4. Must contain at least one symbol.
5. Must be 6 character long.

**In MVC**

We can achieve this by below code:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email).ToHtmlString()))
```

How can we do the same thing in Blazor? Please let me know if more things is required to support the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How to use the same with the validation message in the Blazor. FYI - validation message in Blazor looks as `<ValidationMessage For="@(() => signUpModel.Email)"></ValidationMessage>`

Comment: Ok. So, how to use the `<ValidationSummary/>` with `MarkupString(htmlText) `. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe using your own edit context, the FieldChanged event and reflection to get the message from the model of its invalid, so you can put it in a markup string? Haven't seen a way out of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also need to do this to have a custom validation but that looks like `ValidationMessage` and as you said in the comments

> How to use the same with the validation message in the Blazor. FYI - validation message in Blazor looks as  signUpModel.Email)">

The way to do this is just do the same as `ValidationMessage` does and change how it renders

You can just copy the code from the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6f9502977dd64dc63f5507cded021d8cf0962bf6/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs) and do some changes.

- First, it would be good if you change the name of the class for something like `CustomValidationMessage` or anything you want.
- You will see the method `BuildRenderTree` which is build the html with the validation messages.
- If you know how to use `BuildRenderTree` you can just edit that but I recommend you to remove that method and create a `.razor` file that will render the messages.
- Do the same logic as in that method (foreach the messages) and inside you can render whatever you want (e.g. use `MarkupString(message)`) .

.razor

```
foreach (var message in CurrentEditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier))
{
    @* use message the way you want*@
}
```